# rii mini keyboard doesn't connect anymore, what can I do?

Tags: connection, wireless-keyboard

My rii mini keyboard used to work fine.

I plug it into my Android device or Windows 7 / Ubuntu, and it seems to understand it's a keyboard, however it never connects properly! Is it broken, what could it be? Is there something to I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the nano receiver was actually broken. It had received a hit, but thought it was OK. Bought a new one, and it works great!